# Divide a Line and get its points

Tags: geometry

I have the coordinates for **Point A** and **Point B**.

[image]

Now I want to divide this line in `k` equal parts, and **get the points coordinates** (red lines are the points):

[image]

How do I do this? I know that's a simple formula but I'm having trouble with it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to divide the line into $k$ equal parts, you will need $k-1$ points.

Let $A$ be $(x_A,y_A)$ and $B$ be $(x_B,y_B)$.  The $k-1$ points would be

$$(x_A+\frac{x_B-x_A}{k},y_A+\frac{y_B-y_A}{k})\\(x_A+2\frac{x_B-x_A}{k},y_A+2\frac{y_B-y_A}{k})\\(x_A+3\frac{x_B-x_A}{k},y_A+3\frac{y_B-y_A}{k})\\\dots\\(x_A+(k-1)\frac{x_B-x_A}{k},y_A+(k-1)\frac{y_B-y_A}{k})$$

Note, this works for lines that are horizontal, vertical or "diagonals".  If you know they will be "horizontal", the formula can be simplified (though this one will still work).

Comment: That's what I need ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have the distance $d$ between A and B, because $d = B-A$. You can easily calculate the distance $b$ between every point to the next one, because $b= \frac{d}{k}$ gives the distance.

The points coordinates are now simply $A + b n$ with n the point you want to know with $n$ maximal $k-1$.

Comment: Upvoted ! That answer my question as well !